# Generate a signal with 8 fixed-width pulse with varying interval

Tags: arduino, avr, esp32

I am working on an ultrasound device. We want to generate a particular signal to drive the 1 MHz piezoelectric transducer at various resonance frequencies point.

The goal is to write a code using ATmega328P (Arduino Nano) to generate a signal with an 8 fixed-width pulse with varying intervals as seen in the table below.

[image]

The sample of the signal we are looking for is below: The yellow signal

[image]

I succeeded to find a code to generate an 8 pulses signal at the unique frequency of 1 MHz: The code and the results on the oscilloscope are found below:

```
#define NOP __asm__ __volatile__ ("nop\n\t")

void delayMilliseconds(int ms) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ms; i++) {
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
  }
}

void stopTransducer()
{
  cli();
  TCCR1B = 0;
  sei();
}

void startTransducer(float freq, float dutyCycle)
{
  dutyCycle = dutyCycle * 10.0;
  if (dutyCycle == 0) dutyCycle = 0.0;
  else if (dutyCycle == 1.0) dutyCycle = 0.1;
  else if (dutyCycle == 2.0) dutyCycle = 0.2;
  else if (dutyCycle == 3.0) dutyCycle = 0.3;
  else if (dutyCycle == 4.0) dutyCycle = 0.4;
  else if (dutyCycle == 5.0) dutyCycle = 0.5;
  else if (dutyCycle == 6.0) dutyCycle = 0.6;
  else if (dutyCycle == 7.0) dutyCycle = 0.7;
  else if (dutyCycle == 8.0) dutyCycle = 0.8;
  else if (dutyCycle == 9.0) dutyCycle = 0.9;

  cli();
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS10) | _BV(ICNC1);
  //f0 = fclk / (2 * N * Top)
  long topv = (long) ((float) F_CPU / (freq * 2.0 * 1.0));
  ICR1 = topv;

  //OCR1A = 4;
  OCR1A = (int) ((float) topv * dutyCycle);
  //OCR1B = (int) ((float) topv * (1 - dutyCycle));
  DDRB |= _BV(PORTB1) | _BV(PORTB2);
  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(COM1A0) | _BV(COM1B0) ;
  sei();
}

void setup()
{
  //Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode (3, OUTPUT);

  DDRD |= B01000000;
}

byte a = 0;
unsigned long t_start = 0;
unsigned long t_peak = 0;
unsigned long t = 0;
byte v_peak = 0;
const float SPEED_OF_SOUND_20C = 0.0003432; //per micro-second
float d = 0;

void loop()
{

  startTransducer(1000000.0, 0.5);
  delayMicroseconds(8);
  stopTransducer();

  delayMicroseconds(10);
  DDRD |= B00001000;
  PORTD &= ~(1 << PD3); //set PD3 low

  v_peak = 0;
  t_start = micros();
  t_peak = t_start;

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    a = analogRead(0);
    t = micros();

    if (a > v_peak) {
      t_peak = t;
      v_peak = a;
    }
  }

  t = t_peak - t_start;
  d = (float) t * SPEED_OF_SOUND_20C / 2.0;
  //Serial.println(d , 2);

  PORTD |= 1 << PD3;
  DDRD &= B00000000;
  delay(100);
}
```

This is the result of the code from the oscilloscope:

[image]

[image]

**My Challenge**

How to twist the code above to generate a signal as in figure 1 with ATmega328P (Arduino). I have a little knowledge about timers for AVR, I will appreciate any help.

---

I have updated the code with your suggested modification! This is the result! The pulse width is still having the same period! What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: you already asked this question ... next time, please improve the first question instead of posting a new one

Comment: `How to twist the code above to generate a signal as in figure 1. 
 I have a little knowledge about timers`.... maybe you should instead be asking `how does this code work?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate PWM signal with ESP-32](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619540/generate-pwm-signal-with-esp-32)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, you show a waveform where there are 8 cycles of a 1 MHz square wave, then you say you want 8 pulses at various frequencies. Are you saying you want 1 cycle of each frequency? So it would look like the scope waveform  with 8 'pulses', but each one would be a different width, or do you want 8 cycles of each frequency or what?

Comment: Sorry, if it is not clearer enough @GodJihyo. I am looking to generate a signal that can produce 8 pulses at various frequencies!

Comment: @TechnoKG  You just restated what you already said, so it's still ambiguous. I gave an answer, if it doesn't cover what you meant let me know.

Comment: In place of the numerous "else if", should you choose instead the "case" statement?

Comment: You're confusing the terminology here. If I go by your 'scope trace, then what you're actually looking for is 8 pulses, each with a different *period* (not a different frequency). An individual pulse doesn't really have a "frequency".

Comment: okey, thank you for the terminoly @brhans

Comment: Actually, each of the 8 pulses should have a different period but with the same ON-Time.

Comment: @TechnoKG - Hi, Your "answer" (which wasn't an answer to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) has been added to the question as an edit i.e. an update. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new information. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Also, please [edit] the question to add the code which produced that new waveform. Thanks.

Comment: (Also, if you have made changes specific to one person's answer, then you can leave a short *comment* below their answer (so that they get notified) saying that you have implemented change X ,Y or Z and added the new waveform into the question.)

Comment: @TechnoKG: I think you are saying you want a fixed-width pulse with varying interval.  It doesn't make sense to talk about period for a non-periodic signal -- we use the term "interval" to talk about time between two events.  And while you can talk about frequency content in any signal, you're probably going to be deeply disappointed to find out that most of the energy is unrelated to pulse timing (which you can control in software) but determined by the rise and fall times.  If you want to control those in software, you need to get away from squarewave using a DAC output pin, not a timer pin.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for clarifying for me! Let me review my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with an Teensy 2.0 (atMega32u4@16MHz) with an ocean of NOP's and disabled interrupts. My scope screen looks pretty much like your first screen shot.
You may try that on your atMega328. If it's not runnig at 16 MHz you will see a streched or narrowed timing:

````
// PulseTrain Generator Demo code using Teensy 2.0 (atMega32U4)
// Crystal is 16 MHz
// using Port D4 (Arduino 22) for output
#define OUT_PIN  22

// 62.5ns per NOP, 125ns per CBI and SBI

// PORTD using CBI/SBI instruction = 11, Bit 4
#define OUT_ON  { asm ( "cbi 11,4 \n" ); }
#define OUT_OFF { asm ( "sbi 11,4 \n" ); }

// 6 nop 375 ns
#define PAUSE { \
  asm (     \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    ); \
}

// 29 nop 1812.5ns
#define PULSE_409 { \
  asm (     \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    ); \
}

// 61 nop 3812.5ns
#define PULSE_226 { \
  asm (     \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" \
    ); \
}

// 19 nop 1187.5ns
#define PULSE_560 { \
  asm (     \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    ); \
}

// 10 nop 625ns
#define PULSE_792 { \
  asm (     \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" "nop\n" \
    ); \
}

static void CreatePulseTrain(void) {
   noInterrupts();
   // P1 = 2445 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_409;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P2 = 4425 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_226;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P3 = 2445 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_409;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P4 = 4425 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_226;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P5 = 1786 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_560;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P6 = 1263 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_792;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P7 = 1263 ns
   OUT_ON;   // 125ns
   PULSE_792;
   OUT_OFF;  // 125ns
   PAUSE;    // 375ns
   // P8 = 1263 ns
   OUT_ON;    // 125ns
   PULSE_792; // 625ns
   OUT_OFF;   // 125ns
   PAUSE;     // 375ns
   interrupts();
}

void setup() {
  pinMode (OUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (OUT_PIN, true);
}

void loop() {
  CreatePulseTrain();
  delay (10);
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Usually when talking about pulses of a particular frequency we mean that the device generates the specified frequency for a specified time.

For example, the waveform shown on the scope is an 8 µS pulse of 1 MHz. Since one cycle at 1 MHz is 1 µS, 8 µS gives you 8 cycles. 
You can see where this is done in the code:

```
startTransducer(1000000.0, 0.5);
delayMicroseconds(8);
stopTransducer();
```

To get pulses like this of different frequencies you would call startTransducer() and delayMicroseconds()with different parameters.
For example, to get 8 cycles of 409 KHz you would use:

```
startTransducer(409000.0, 0.5);
delayMicroseconds(19.56);
stopTransducer();
```

The 19.56 delay value is the width of one cycle at 409 KHz times 8 cycles.

$$ 8~*~(~1~/~409000~Hz~)~=~19.56~\mu S $$

So you would just have to call those functions with the appropriate values for frequency and the delay to get the number of cycles you need.

Comment: Hello @Godjihyo

Thank for the contribution! It is true I have misused the term!

Comment: Actually, each of the 8 pulses should have a different period but with the same ON-Time. –

Answer (score 0):

If you must use an ATmega328P, your master clock is far to low to reach the requested timing precision using high language. Whatever you write as delay will be rounded to the possible resolution of NOPs, dec loops or timer ticks. The function call overhead makes all worse. The only chance I see here, is to disable interrupts during the complex burst generation and write a long assembly sequence of CBI, SBI and NOP instructions and small dec loops to "manually" create the timing. With a 20 MHz crystal you have a resolution of 50ns(NOP) and 100ns(CBI/SBI)) per instruction. It's a pain to cook this. An much faster ESP32 will give you here more comfort, because you probably can create such a burst using high language.

Looking at your last screen shot I think you want to create a kind of unique chirp, that can be identified on reception. I assume the yellow track is the transducer voltage. You seem to use only one power transistor and a flyback coil or transformer to feed the piezo. The self resonant frequency of the piezo is not suppressed this way, the ringing has a large amplitude. With this hardware the spectral output of your system is far away from what I think you want to produce. The receiver will have a hard work to filter out the self resonant frequency part of the signal. I recommend a stronger guidance of the piezo voltage with a higher voltage class AB driver (power opamp), which will suppress the SRF by 10-20 dB.

I had a quick look at Arduino due and ESP32 and how the implementation would look there. The Due has no operation system running and the cpu is "yours". Precise timing as you need is possible using C.
The ESP32 has a nice hardware feature: You can read the number of exec cycles of the cpu as int. With this you can program delay loops with around 6-7ns resolution by polling the counter (see: ESP.getCycleCount()). But the operating system can execute tasks with higher priority if you don'nt care for this. So you would have to read a lot to avoid such traps. The timer hardware is very capable as well, but I didn't play with it under this aspect.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! @Jens for your contribution! 
It is true I am also looking for a solution using ESP32 but I am not familiar with the board.

Maybe you can give me some guidelines for ESP32! thank you